# Asignar una variable al mismo tiempo de crear un Faker en Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, artisan, faker

Tengo una tabla que necesito que vaya el nombre completo, y al momento de generarlo mediante Faker, e intentado algunos pasos pero no me asigna el valor deseado.

```
'user_id' => 1,
'name'  => $this->faker->name(),
'lastname'  =>$this->faker->lastName(),
'full_name'=> 
'document'=> $this->faker->bothify('#########'),
'address'=> $this->faker->address()


introducir el código aquí
```

La idea es que en 'full_name' vaya el dato de 'name' + 'lastname'. he intentado varias opciones, quedo atento.

```
  $name = "";
  $lastname = "";

     return [
        

        'user_id' => 1,
        'name', $name  => $this->faker->name(),
        'lastname' , $lastname  =>$this->faker->lastName(),
        'full_name'=> $name.$lastname,
        'document'=> $this->faker->bothify('#########'),
        'address'=> $this->faker->address()

    ];
```

he intentado codigo similar pero no me funciona, me sale que estoy pasando parametros de más.

Comment: Estas asignando un string vacío a las variables... y después estás usando las variables como claves del array en vez de como valor...

Comment: las creo para inicializarlas, la idea es que name y lastname puedan ir en la variable full_name al mismo tiempo de crearlas.

Comment: Ok, pero no entiendo por que le asignas un string vacio como valor en vez de asignarle el valor que quieres que tenga. O sea, haces `$name = "";` en vez de `$name = $this->faker->name();`

Comment: Y luego pones el valor de esa variable como clave del array en vez de como valor de la clave del array. O sea, pones `$name  => $this->faker->name()` en vez de `'name' => $name`

Answer (score 0):

Te dice que tienes parámetros de más porque estás pasando el string 'lastname' y el string 'name' . Y además como $name y $lastname son strings en blanco, lo que devuelves contiene:

```
  return [
    'name', 
    ''  => $this->faker->name(),
    'lastname' , 
    ''  => $this->faker->lastName(),
    'full_name' => ''
   ];
```

Sería más sencillo hacer:

```
 $name = $this->faker->name();
 $lastname = $this->faker->lastName();

 return [
    'user_id' => 1,
    'name' => $name,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'full_name'=> $name.' '.$lastname,
    'document'=> $this->faker->bothify('#########'),
    'address'=> $this->faker->address()
 ];
```